# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Forgive me, I'm completely new to using JSON/JSONP/AJAX and have been researching this extensively for the last 24 hours and can't figure it out.  Your help would be appreciated.

I am trying to get information out of a simple JSON file from another server and display it very plainly on my website.

The JSON file I'm trying to pull information from:
http://evewho.com/api.php?type=corplist&id=98224089

I'm trying to display just the character names from that JSON here inside the #characters div:
http://anomaly47.com/jsonp_test.html

So far I am just trying to connect and see the objects information using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = 'http://evewho.com/api.php?type=corplist&id=98224089&callback=?';

  $.getJSON(url, null, function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
  )

});
```

I keep getting the following error in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 
api.php?type=corplist&id=98224089&callback=jQuery1111010067848535254598_1425072137785&_=14250721377…:1

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks again!

Comment: try to change `'&callback=?'` to `'&jsoncallback=?'`

Comment: Changed it out and now received a similar error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : api.php?type=corplist&id=98224089&jsoncallback=jQuery111106458904333412647_1425073376470&_=14250733…:1

Comment: @anomaly47 All options for cross-origin requests require some support by the endpoint being requested. They're not default features of HTTP, so the owners must intentionally add that support. It may be that it's just expecting a different parameter name than `callback=`, as levi tried to suggest. You should check the API's documentation for any information on using JSONP with it. Though, if it doesn't offer support, the request may simply not be possible with Ajax alone.

Answer (score 1):

Not all API's that serve json are accessible using ajax.

Your API is not returning `jsonp` data format and is not CORS enabled.

If it is your site, and you are making request from the same domain, remove the `&callback=?` from url since this tells jQuery that request is for `jsonp`.

If it is a cross domain request you will need to set up a proxy on your server to retrieve the data and make your ajax call to your proxy script